# MySQL copying from one table to another removes accents

Tags: mysql, utf-8, diacritics

ok so the problems is a bit diffrent from what i originally though.

i have both of these values for city :

`'1520', 'Gossendorf'`

`'3358', 'Gösselsdorf'`

and if i do:
`select city from cities where city = 'Gösselsdorf'`

the first result comes up ( even due it is not with accents ) !

why?

Comment: which OS/MySQL version/language settings/client etc. ?

Comment: what are the language settings used from the client ?

Comment: server/client are both local. what do you mean language settings for client?

Comment: eihter Windows itself or the DB client and the used connection string (like in ADO.NET provider or JDBC or...)

Comment: windows itself? what does that have to do with it ? add the connection string to the question.

Comment: trry using `+ "; CharSet=UTF8";` at the end - depending on the driver/client you use it could be `+ "; charset =UTF8";` instead!

Comment: it happens even if i run it from mysql.exe.. so i dont think the connection string has anything to do with it.

Comment: then it seems that your DB installation is somehow defective... or somehow using your Windows language settings!

Comment: i dont think so, since only copying have this problem, but thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to anyone interested:

the solution for this is as follows:

`select city from cities where BINARY city = 'Gösselsdorf'`